# Sort array based on order value within second array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have two Arrays:

```
const dropdownOptions = [
  { text: 'NuxtJS', sortOrder: 1 },
  { text: 'VueJS', sortOrder: 2 },
]
```

And:

```
const sidebar = [
  {
    text: 'VueJS',
    collapsible: true,
    items: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    text: 'NuxtJS',
    collapsible: true,
    items: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  }
]
```

I'd like to sort the sidebar variable based on the `sortOrder` value within the dropdownOptions array. So, for this example, the expected output would be:

```
const sortedSidebar = [
  {
    text: 'NuxtJS',
    collapsible: true,
    items: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    text: 'VueJS',
    collapsible: true,
    items: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first convert your `dropdownOptions` into a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) that associates each `text`/item with an order for quick and easy lookup. Below I've done that by creating a `Map` using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on `dropdownOptions`, but if you can change the `dropdownOptions` data structure then you can avoid this step and build the Map directly. Once you have the Map, you can use [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) on the difference of the orders to rearrange your array in ascending order based on the `sortOrder` property held within the Map.

See working example below:

```js
const dropdownOptions = [ { text: 'NuxtJS', sortOrder: 1 }, { text: 'VueJS', sortOrder: 2 }, ];
const sidebar = [ { text: 'VueJS', collapsible: true, items: [] }, { text: 'NuxtJS', collapsible: true, items: [] } ];

const sortMap = new Map(dropdownOptions.map((obj) => [obj.text, obj.sortOrder]));
const sortedSidebar = sidebar.slice().sort((a, b) => sortMap.get(a.text) - sortMap.get(b.text));
console.log(sortedSidebar);
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like...

```
const dropdownOptionsMap = dropdownOptions.reduce((a,v)=>{ a[v.text]=v; return a; },{});
const sortedSidebar = sidebar.slice().sort((a,b) => { return dropdownOptionsMap[a.text].sortOrder - dropdownOptionsMap[b.text]; });
```

Comment: Appreciate the reply. I decided to go with Nick because of his extensive reasoning behind his decisions.